# Permission to a group on button click in odoo 14

Tags: odoo-14

i have create a group in security.xml as

```
   <record id="group_requester" model="res.groups">
       <field name="name">Requester</field>
       <field name="category_id" ref="IT_asset_module.module_category_it_assets"/>
       <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
   </record>
```

and in view.xml as

```
   <button name="action_submit" states="draft" string="Submit" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="IT_asset_module.group_requester"/>
```

But when i click on button following error occur;

You are not allowed to access 'System Parameter' (ir.config_parameter) records.
This operation is allowed for the following groups:
- Administration/Settings
Contact your administrator to request access if necessary.

I do not want to give Administration/Settings access to user.
Please guide.

Comment: I think you should try simple create group and add manually in user setting and try.Try to remove category_id and implied ids and test it.I used groups like that in my module.

Comment: I have remove category_id and implied_ids but still same. Please guide any code written in ir.model.access.csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change implied_ids to:

```
<field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_system'))]"/>
```

or add your group in model ir.config_parameter inside your module security/ir.model.access.csv

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_ir_config_parameter_requester,config_parameter_requester,base.model_ir_config_parameter,IT_asset_module.group_requester,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: with base.group_system, Administration/Settings permission assigned and Accounting, Apps and Setting allow to user. I do not want to give these permission to user.

Comment: I have _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin'] can you guide group related to these, those i can add against group_requester.

Comment: Thank you. By changing in security/ir.model.access.csv file my problem has been solved.